# Barba wrapper not found

Tags: javascript, html, barbajs

I'm trying to do page transitions with barba.js, I used the data-barba="wrapper" and data-barba="container" exactly like in the documentary.
Here's a shorten code of the html:

```
<body class="page" data-barba="wrapper">
<header class=nav-header>
<!-- Some navbar stuff -->
</header>
<main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
<!-- Some main stuff -->
</main>

<!-- Some divs -->
</body>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
barba.init({
    views: [
        {
            namespace: 'home',
            beforeEnter() {
                animateSlides();
            },
            beforeLeave() {
                slideScene.destroy();
                pageScene.destroy();
                controller.destroy();
            }
        },
        {
            namespace: 'fashion'
        }
    ]
});
```

This is the error showing up in the console when opening the website

```
Uncaught Error: [@barba/core] No Barba wrapper found
    at t.e.init (core.ts:184)
    at app.js:127
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem solved it by moving the script tag inside the wrapper(body)
from the head
.

```
<body class="page" data-barba="wrapper">
<header class=nav-header>
<!-- Some navbar stuff -->
</header>
<main data-barba="container" data-barba-namespace="home">
<!-- Some main stuff -->
</main>

<!-- Some divs -->
<!--script tag here instead of head-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me, it didn't work since I didn't open liveserver.
I didn't know at first that it needs a server to work.
This video https://youtu.be/2AG4YwicMcI?t=10 gives a good explanation

Comment: Please consider adding the relevant details from that video to your answer. It helps future visitors if that video is ever removed.